# Is there a way to programmatically add some default message to git commit?

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I am trying to auto generate my commit message title fetching directly from Phrabricator or Jira.

I have a bash script that does a http call and get the title.

I know you can have a commit template for each commit message.

eg.

`~/.gitconfig`

```
[commit]
    template = ~/.gitmessage
```

`~/.gitmessage`

```
Some template for user
```

But is it possible to dynamically generate commit template using bash or python scripts?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the git client side hook prepare-commit-msg. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

The prepare-commit-msg hook is run before the commit message editor is fired up but after the default message is created. It lets you edit the default message before the commit author sees it. This hook takes a few parameters: the path to the file that holds the commit message so far, the type of commit, and the commit SHA-1 if this is an amended commit. This hook generally isn’t useful for normal commits; rather, it’s good for commits where the default message is auto-generated, such as templated commit messages, merge commits, squashed commits, and amended commits. You may use it in conjunction with a commit template to programmatically insert information.

Answer (score 1):

You want to provide a `prepare-commit-msg` hook; a sample appears in `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers: if you want to commit immediately (not fire up an editor with pre-filled contents), try this:

```
git commit -m"$(... whatever command outputs your commit message ...)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git commit -m "Your default message" && git commit --amend`.